# Reordering elements in Rss20FeedFormatter serialisation

Tags: c#, .net, xml, rss

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to re-order the elements in an RSS item. I guess I can manually serialise it but just wondering if there's something simpler.

.NET serialises things as

```
<item>
<link>http://mmu.ac.uk/library.aspx</link>
<title>URGENT Library information: borrowing facilities withdrawn</title>
<description/>
</item>
```

Wheras I am using a JQuery news ticker that expects this to be in a different order

```
<item>
<title>URGENT Library information: borrowing facilities withdrawn</title>
<description/>
<link>http://mmu.ac.uk/library.aspx</link>
</item>
```

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You could override the WriteItem method in a derived "MyRss20FeedFormatter" class and change the order in which the syndicationItems data is written to the outputstream

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.rss20feedformatter.writeitem.aspx

Comment: Thanks - it's not allowing me to access an number of private variables such as Rss20Constants - I think it's probably easier just to use xslt!